# shopware login not work so what is actual issuse?

Tags: shopware

I have setup shopware on a localhost server.
I have created a customer for login but when try to login with created customer no change in the page. It means only the login and register page show, Redirect to other pages are not working.

If I can try to open profile page or addresses page, page not opens only show login or register.

So What is the problem?? **Additional setting required for login**?

In the Top navigation account tab Login name show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Shopware/Configs/Default.php#L207

You should check if this fits your server configuration and database or change it via config.php. Login issues are often caused by timezone differences between php and database.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Timezone must be same as the server for the login to work properly.